# Seperating retrieved data from MYSQL for Json (Preparing for API C#)

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to prepare data as Json for my API, this is the code i currently have:

```
if(isset($_GET)) {
    include('db.php');
    $result = mysqli_query(
        $con,
        "SELECT * FROM `vragen`");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $vraag_ID = $row['vraag_ID'];
            $vraagnummer = $row['vraagnummer'];
            $vraag = $row['vraag'];
            response($vraag_ID, $vraagnummer, $vraag);
    }

}

function response($vraag_ID, $vraagnummer, $vraag)
{

    $response['vraag_ID'] = $vraag_ID;
    $response['vraagnummer'] = $vraagnummer;
    $response['vraag'] = $vraag;
    $response = [$response];
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
```

Which outputs this Data:

```
[{"vraag_ID":"1","vraagnummer":"1","vraag":"Vraag1Vraag1Vraag1Vraag1"}][{"vraag_ID":"2","vraagnummer":"2","vraag":"Vraag2Vraag2Vraag2Vraag2"}][{"vraag_ID":"3","vraagnummer":"3","vraag":"Vraag3Vraag3Vraag3Vraag3"}][{"vraag_ID":"4","vraagnummer":"4","vraag":"Vraag4Vraag4Vraag4Vraag4"}][{"vraag_ID":"5","vraagnummer":"5","vraag":"Vraag5Vraag5Vraag5Vraag5"}]
```

Obviously this is isn't "Json ready" yet and outputs it just as plain text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need such a function, you are overcomplicating the task. Just build your array directly into the `while` loop:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET)) {
        include('db.php');
        $result = mysqli_query(
            $con,
            "SELECT * FROM `vragen`");

        $response = [];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

And within your `SELECT` you can specify upfont which fields to be included.